define command of form \command[a=1](2,3)(4){5}
The package tkz-euclide has an interesting syntax in many commands, such as \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}, where some arguments are given in parentheses.
I have taken a look at the .zip folder from CTAN, but it is quite elaborate and I was not able to emulate the command definitions.
So I can get started more easily, how could I, say, define a command of the form \jasper[mynum=5](1,2,3)(4){5}?
I know how to define keys, and I can even construct commands which use parentheses. I just can't seem to tie it all together.
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\makeatletter

% I can use keys as follows
\pgfqkeys{/jasper}{
    .is family
    ,a/.store in=\jasper@a
    ,a=1
}
\newcommand{\jasper}[2][]{
    \pgfqkeys{/jasper}{#1}
    \draw (0,\jasper@a) -- (#2);
}

% I can use parentheses in commands as follows
\def\jaspertwo(#1,#2)(#3){
    \draw (3,#1) -- (5,#2);
    \draw (0,0) circle[radius=#3];
}


% I want to make a command of the form \jasper[a=5](1,2)(3){4}, this is my attempt

%\def\jasperthree(#2,#3)(#4){
%    \pgfqkeys{/jasper}{#1}
%    \draw (3,#2) -- (5,#3);
%    \draw (0,0) circle[radius=#4];
%    \draw (1,1) circle[radius=\jasper@a];
%    \draw (1,2) circle[radius=#5]
%}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \jasper[a=5]{1,1}
    \jaspertwo(4,5)(6)
    %\jasperthree[a=5](5,6)(7){8}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



You should look at \NewDocumentCommand and the d or D argument type. See the user commands guide.

@jlab Thank you, I wasn't aware of this resource!

To define a command which uses brace for its arguments, a simple way is to use the d argument type with \NewDocumentCommand (described in the LaTeX user commands guide). For example, the syntax:
\NewDocumentCommand{\jasper}{ O{} d() d() m }{%
...

correspond to #1 between square brackets [...], #2 and #3 between parentheses (...) and #4 as a mandatory argument, typically between brackets {}. You can also define default values for #2 and #3 using D(){default value} instead of d().
In your example, you treat separately the coordinates given in the first parenthesis (what makes the syntax not very clear for me). Your example doesn't correspond to a real situation so it's hard to say what is the better way to implement that. But using \NewDocumentCommand functionnalities, you could try the \SplitList argument preprocessor:
\NewDocumentCommand{\jasper}{ O{} >{\SplitList{,}} d() d() m }{%
  \pgfqkeys{/jasper}{#1}
  \jasper@drawline #2
  \draw (0,0) circle[radius=#3];
  \draw (1,1) circle[radius=\jasper@a];
  \draw (1,2) circle[radius=#4];
}

which needs an auxiliary command with 2 arguments (assuming that #2 in \jasper contains 2 values)
\def\jasper@drawline#1#2{%
  \draw (3,#1) -- (5,#2);%
}

Full example:
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\makeatletter

% I can use keys as follows
\pgfqkeys{/jasper}{
  .is family
  ,a/.store in=\jasper@a
  ,a=1
}

\def\jasper@drawline#1#2{%
  \draw (3,#1) -- (5,#2);%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\jasper}{ O{} >{\SplitList{,}} d() d() m }{%
  \pgfqkeys{/jasper}{#1}
  \jasper@drawline #2
  \draw (0,0) circle[radius=#3];
  \draw (1,1) circle[radius=\jasper@a];
  \draw (1,2) circle[radius=#4];
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \jasper[a=5](5,6)(7){8}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


